# How to change currency symbol to dollar ($) in Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

After installing Umbraco 7, apparently the default currency symbol is pound (£).

How do you change that to dollar ($)?

I tried adding this line in web.config but it didn't do anything.

```
<globalization requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" culture="en-AU" uiCulture="en-AU" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this functionality hasn't changed from previous versions so you need to set the culture for the domain at the root/homepage node of your content branch.

If the culture isn't listed, you need to add it under the "Settings > Languages" section.

Answer (score 0):

Here's detailed steps on how to set the locale of the Umbraco site, this will set the currency & language.

**1. Add the language**

Settings > Languages > Create > Select the required language > Create

**2. Apply the language**

Content > Select the root node > Actions (top right) > Culture and Hostnames > Select the language you just added > Save

**3. Remove the unused language - for housekeeping**

Settings > Languages > Select the unused language > Delete

FYI:
Umbraco locale overrides web.config `<globalization>` values and Azure App Settings

Steps apply to Umbraco version 7.6.4